# React-Native Async function Failed in IOS Simulator

Tags: ios, react-native, async-await, ios-simulator

I have below simple code which work fine in Android but in IOS await doesn't work.

```
const CheckAsyncfucntion = async () => {
console.log('Before Await execution');
const authenticateuser = await newUser(registration_id); // return true or false
console.log('After Await Execution => ', authenticateuser);
}
```

in andorid it work fine. but in ios both the log are getting print with undefined value of authenticateuser. and after that newUser value is getting return.

Any Lead in this will be appreciated.
Am using IOS smiulator iphone12 iOS 15.0

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is in the function `newUser`.

My iOS simulator works just fine with any async functions like below.

```js
  const CheckAsyncfucntion = async () => {
    console.log('Before Await execution');
    // return true or false from Promise
    const authenticateuser = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(true);
      }, 2000);
    });
    console.log('After Await Execution => ', authenticateuser);
  };

CheckAsyncfucntion();
```

Comment: The New User function is a Axios Instance export default function which call Rest API and check if user is a new user or not.